# TypeError: Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

На локальном сервере все работает, а когда захостил на хероку видает ошибку

```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined
2022-01-06T11:47:50.492354+00:00 app[web.1]:     at getData (/app/requests/weather-request.js:16:42)
2022-01-06T11:47:50.492355+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
2022-01-06T11:47:50.492355+00:00 app[web.1]:     at async postData (/app/controllers/search-controller.js:10:18)
2022-01-06T11:47:50.492654+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
2022-01-06T11:47:50.492655+00:00 app[web.1]:     at postData (/app/controllers/search-controller.js:11:24)
2022-01-06T11:47:50.492655+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

Вот мой код:

weather_request:

```
// import node-fetch
// const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const fetch = (...args) =>
  import('node-fetch').then(({ default: fetch }) => fetch(...args))

// import dotenv
require('dotenv').config()

const getData = async (city = 'Lviv') => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${process.env.API_KEY}`
    )

    const data = await response.json()
    const celsius = Math.round(data.main.temp - 273.15)
    const minTemp = Math.round(data.main.temp_min - 273.15)
    const maxTemp = Math.round(data.main.temp_max - 273.15)

    return {
      name: data.name,
      country: data.sys.country,
      temp: celsius,
      icon:
        'https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/' + data.weather[0].icon + '.png',
      description: data.weather[0].description,
      humidity: data.main.humidity,
      wind: data.wind.speed,
      min: minTemp,
      max: maxTemp,
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}

module.exports = getData
```

search_controller:

```
// import createPath
const createPath = require('../helpers/create-path')
// import getData function
const getData = require('../requests/weather-request')

// post controller
const postData = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { city } = req.body
    const data = await getData(city)
    const title = data.name

    res.render(createPath('index'), { title, data })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}

module.exports = postData
```

server.js:

```
// MODULES
// import express
const express = require('express')
// import dotenv
require('dotenv').config()
// import morgan
const morgan = require('morgan')
// import createPath
const createPath = require('./helpers/create-path')
// import search route
const searchRoute = require('./routes/search-route')

const app = express()

// initialization of ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

// MIDDLEWARES
// morgan logger middleware
app.use(morgan(':method :url :status :res[content-length] - :response-time ms'))
// middleware for static files
app.use(express.static(__dirname))
// middleware for work with method POST
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// ROUTES
// main route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const title = 'Home'

  res.render(createPath('home'), { title })
})

// post route
app.use(searchRoute)

// error route
app.use((req, res) => {
  const title = 'Error'
  res.status(400).render(createPath('error'), { title })
})

// LISTEN
// start server
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, (error) => {
  error ? console.log(error) : console.log(`Listening port ${process.env.PORT}`)
})
```

Comment: скорее всего у вас не определены переменные окружения, в том числе process.env.API_KEY. почитайте https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42109813/node-js-environment-variables-and-heroku-deployment

Comment: nörbörnën все есть, ничего не забил, могу кинуть гитхаб профиль, посмотрите, склонируете